# Как правильно сказать?

Tags: письменность

Как правильно писать "купить билет А - Б" или "купить билет по маршруту А - Б"?

Comment: Меня интересует, если я пишу письмо в деловом стиле (претензию), будет ли ошибкой указать "приобрела билет Москва - Санкт-Петербург"? Обязательно ли писать "приобрела билет по маршруту Москва - Санкт-Петербург"? Чем это обусловлено?

Comment: Думаю, совсем не обязательно. 
При чем тут вообще маршрут? У Вас билет не на маргрут, а на поезд (самолет, автобус, пароход, дилижанс).

Лучше, как предложили: "билет на рейс № 12345, 31 марта 20.. г.", "на поезд №1 отправлением 23:59 49-го мартобря 2099 г." и т.д. 
А если суть претензии - в самом билете, то спишите его тоное название с документа, да ещё и номер его укажите. 
Тут юридическая точность важнее лингвистической.

Comment: Я редактирую тексты обращений. Написала "приобрела билет Москва - Санкт-Петербург". Сотрудник, в чьей компетентности я не уверена, оставил комментарий, что предложение составлено неграмотно, я должна писать "приобрела билет по маршруту Москва - Санкт-Петербург". Хочу знать наверняка, как я должна писать.

Comment: Ясно. Нет, я не вижу никакой необходимости в добавлении слова "маршрут". Почему - уже сказал: билет - он не на маршрут, а на поезд.
Вряд ли можно тут найти четкое правило или указание. Это что-то скорее из стилистики, правил на все случаи не существует.  
Впрочем, я тоже не никак не авторитет тут, может кто-то более компетентный и даст такую цитату.

Comment: Людмила, спасибо за ответ. В претензии все данные указываются обязательно. Если я пишу "00.00.00 я приобрела билет А - Б на поезд № 00 А - С, отправлением 00.00.00 в 00:00", требуется ли мне вставлять "по маршруту"? Маршрут поезда и маршрут в билете при этом не совпадают.

Comment: Уважаемый behemothus, Вам также благодарна.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы написала: приобрела билет на поезд № ... " Москва - Санкт-Петербург". По-моему,так часто пишется в документах и устно тоже говорится. А вот "билет  Москва - Санкт-Петербург" потребует в деловом общении уточнения, какой - железнодорожный, авиа, автомобильный. Может, сотрудник и прав. А лучше указать все данные, как предлагает behemothus.

Answer (score 0):

Сдается мне, это вопрос не по русскому языку. 
Для понимания вполне достаточно будет "билет  Москва - Одесса". И если вы оформляете, скажем, отчет по командировке, то так и пишете. А если это какой-то сугубо официальный текст, то, может, не лишне будет и "(стоимость) билетов для проезда по маршруту Москва - Одесса".
Без слова "проезд" упоминание "маршрута" кажется несколько неестественным.

Comment: билет на *рейс* "А—Б", на поезд *сообщением*... (от вида транспорта)

Comment: Можно и так, но это если билет на конкретный рейс.